# cannot import name 'PartialState' from 'accelerate' when using Huggingface pipeline on Kaggle notebook?

Tags: python, pipeline, huggingface-transformers, kaggle

When import pipeline from Huggingface on Kaggle notebook,

```
from transformers import pipeline
```

it throws this error:

```
/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/__init__.py:98: UserWarning: unable to load libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: unable to open file: libtensorflow_io_plugins.so, from paths: ['/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io_plugins.so']
caused by: ['/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: undefined symbol: _ZN3tsl6StatusC1EN10tensorflow5error4CodeESt17basic_string_viewIcSt11char_traitsIcEENS_14SourceLocationE']
  warnings.warn(f"unable to load libtensorflow_io_plugins.so: {e}")
/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/__init__.py:104: UserWarning: file system plugins are not loaded: unable to open file: libtensorflow_io.so, from paths: ['/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io.so']
caused by: ['/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/tensorflow_io/python/ops/libtensorflow_io.so: undefined symbol: _ZTVN10tensorflow13GcsFileSystemE']
  warnings.warn(f"file system plugins are not loaded: {e}")
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py:1172, in _LazyModule._get_module(self, module_name)
   1171 try:
-> 1172     return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
   1173 except Exception as e:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py:126, in import_module(name, package)
    125         level += 1
--> 126 return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1050, in _gcd_import(name, package, level)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1027, in _find_and_load(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1006, in _find_and_load_unlocked(name, import_)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:688, in _load_unlocked(spec)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>:883, in exec_module(self, module)

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:241, in _call_with_frames_removed(f, *args, **kwds)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py:44
     35 from ..utils import (
     36     HUGGINGFACE_CO_RESOLVE_ENDPOINT,
     37     is_kenlm_available,
   (...)
     42     logging,
     43 )
---> 44 from .audio_classification import AudioClassificationPipeline
     45 from .automatic_speech_recognition import AutomaticSpeechRecognitionPipeline

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/audio_classification.py:21
     20 from ..utils import add_end_docstrings, is_torch_available, logging
---> 21 from .base import PIPELINE_INIT_ARGS, Pipeline
     24 if is_torch_available():

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py:36
     35 from ..image_processing_utils import BaseImageProcessor
---> 36 from ..modelcard import ModelCard
     37 from ..models.auto.configuration_auto import AutoConfig

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/modelcard.py:48
     32 from .models.auto.modeling_auto import (
     33     MODEL_FOR_AUDIO_CLASSIFICATION_MAPPING_NAMES,
     34     MODEL_FOR_CAUSAL_LM_MAPPING_NAMES,
   (...)
     46     MODEL_FOR_ZERO_SHOT_IMAGE_CLASSIFICATION_MAPPING_NAMES,
     47 )
---> 48 from .training_args import ParallelMode
     49 from .utils import (
     50     MODEL_CARD_NAME,
     51     cached_file,
   (...)
     57     logging,
     58 )

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/training_args.py:67
     66 if is_accelerate_available():
---> 67     from accelerate import PartialState
     68     from accelerate.utils import DistributedType

ImportError: cannot import name 'PartialState' from 'accelerate' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/__init__.py)

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 2
      1 from transformers import AutoModelForSequenceClassification, AutoTokenizer
----> 2 from transformers import pipeline

File <frozen importlib._bootstrap>:1075, in _handle_fromlist(module, fromlist, import_, recursive)

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py:1162, in _LazyModule.__getattr__(self, name)
   1160     value = self._get_module(name)
   1161 elif name in self._class_to_module.keys():
-> 1162     module = self._get_module(self._class_to_module[name])
   1163     value = getattr(module, name)
   1164 else:

File /opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/transformers/utils/import_utils.py:1174, in _LazyModule._get_module(self, module_name)
   1172     return importlib.import_module("." + module_name, self.__name__)
   1173 except Exception as e:
-> 1174     raise RuntimeError(
   1175         f"Failed to import {self.__name__}.{module_name} because of the following error (look up to see its"
   1176         f" traceback):\n{e}"
   1177     ) from e

RuntimeError: Failed to import transformers.pipelines because of the following error (look up to see its traceback):
cannot import name 'PartialState' from 'accelerate' (/opt/conda/lib/python3.10/site-packages/accelerate/__init__.py)
```

**How do I resolve this error?**

Answer (score 7):

If you're seeing this error inside Kaggle notebooks, try installing from source,

```
! pip install -U git+https://github.com/huggingface/transformers.git
! pip install -U git+https://github.com/huggingface/accelerate.git
```

Then restart the kernel by clicking **"Restart and clear cell outputs"**,

[image]

Now the imports will work without the error.

Answer (score 3):

Kaggle containers struggle to balance being up-to-date and compatibility on lots (!) of libraries. **Upgrade minimalistically** `accelerate` (don't upgrade the whole `transformers` module) and **prefer stable pip releases**  over git sources (to not catch some unmature code, unless for a good reason). Don't need to restart the notebook. This line does the job:

```
!pip install -U accelerate --quiet
from transformers import pipeline
```

Answer (score 0):

This is due to out-of-sync packages. Install the previous stable version of transformers until this is fixed:

```
pip install transformers==4.28.0
```

Then restart the notebook, and it should run fine